# How can I use sed to snip a line off of a string?

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, grep, string

I'm writing a script to display the domain registrar info and I'm trying to snip off a few lines from what I already have I currently have it grabbing all the indented text from a whois. Now I'm wanting to remove the Domain name, Whois server, and Referral URL. I've found a sed to remove a line based off of what it starts with but it doesn't seem to work because I'm trying to use it with an existing string rather than an existing file. How can I modify this to work?

```
#!/bin/bash
cyan='\033[0;34m'
white='\033[1;37m'
purple='\033[38;5;129m'
NC='\033[0m'

reg=$(whois "$1" | grep -Ei '^[[:blank:]]+.*:[[:blank:]]' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')
reg1=$(sed /^Domain/d $reg)
printf "${cyan}Below is my best attempt at finding Registrar data:\n"
printf "${white}$reg${NC}\n${purple}Made by Noah Yamamoto${NC}\n"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using sed with a string

You have correctly identified the problem: `$reg` is a string, not a file.  Thus, you need to supply the string to `sed` as stdin.  Replace:

```
reg1=$(sed /^Domain/d $reg)
```

with (for bash):

```
reg1=$(sed /^Domain/d <<<"$reg")
```

Or, for a general POSIX shell, use:

```
reg1=$(echo "$reg" | sed /^Domain/d)
```

#### Simplification: combining the grep and sed commands into one command

The grep and two sed commands can be combined into one sed command:

```
#!/bin/bash
cyan='\033[0;34m'
white='\033[1;37m'
purple='\033[38;5;129m'
NC='\033[0m'

reg=$(whois yahoo.com  | sed -En '/^[[:space:]]*Domain/d; /: / s/^[[:blank:]]+//p')
printf "${cyan}Below is my best attempt at finding Registrar data:\n"
printf "${white}$reg${NC}\n${purple}Made by Noah Yamamoto${NC}\n"
```